# Usage of class in CSS

Tags: css

can someone please explain the difference in the following:

```
div.main 
{
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}

.main div 
{
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I'm not sure when to use each one.

Comment: The first matches all `div`s with class `main`, the second matches all `div`s _contained in_ any element with class `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a sample `HTML` code for each `css` style:

**First example** - Targets all `div` that has a class of `main`

```css
div.main {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>SAMPLE</p>
</div>
```

**Second example** - Targets all `div` that is a child of an element that has the class of `main`

```css
.main div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>NOT AFFECTED</p>
  <div>
    <p>AFFECTED</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>AFFECTED</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>AFFECTED</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>AFFECTED</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn all this by implemeting it or by reading css selectors and css specificity.

For more info [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

```
div.main { font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}
```

Above code will target all div which having `main` as class.

```
.main div { font-family:Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Above code will target all div which is child of `main` class.

Answer (score 0):

**Your first rule says:**

Find all `div` elements having `main` class

**Your second rule says:**

Find **all divs** that are placed inside **all elements** having `main` class.

Please read about basic concepts of CSS